# RESTful concepts: organising hierarchical resources

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I'm trying to organise REST api for several users types, but I don't understand how resources should be invested in each other. For example, administrator can manipulate with employees list (create, edit and remove items). Also administrator can manipulate list of workplaces for each employee. I think that api routes should be such as:

```
GET:    /employees
GET:    /employees/{id}
POST:   /employees
PUT:    /employees/{id}
DELETE: /employees/{id}

GET:    /employees/{id}/workplaces
GET:    /employees/{id}/workplaces/{id}
POST:   /employees/{id}/workplaces
PUT:    /employees/{id}/workplaces/{id}
DELETE: /employees/{id}/workplaces/{id}
```

I know if resource with that `id` does not exist then I should return `404: Not found`, but what about `GET: /employees/{id}/workplaces/{id}`? Should I return `404: Not found` in both cases when employee or workplace with that `id` does not exist? Or maybe exists other solution for this task?

Another problem is that users with different permissions have different access to resources. For example, Head of Department can get a list of employees of his Department, but can't get a list of other Departments. I propose the following API paths:

```
GET: /departments/my/employees
GET: /departments/my/employees/{id}
```

As you can see above, I propose to replace the `id` on the key word `my`, which would mean that the `id` of department must be taken from authorization token. Other users who have more permissions and who can list departments can do something like this:

```
GET: /departments/{id}/employees
GET: /departments/{id}/employees/{id}
```

Is this is a true way to build REST service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what about `GET: /employees/{id}/workplaces/{id}?` Should I return `404: Not found` in both cases when employee or workplace with that id does not exist?

Yes.

> `GET: /departments/my/employees`

If your code can distinguish `my` from real IDs, this is fine from a REST point of view.